# How I can Use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] for wp multisite

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain, wpmu

I have created a subdomain site using wp **multisite function**. Now if i want to access the Sub-Domain files and folders and all the posts to my main domain site can I do it by including `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`?

If i can then How to do that If I can not then how to access those files to main domain?

Note all my subdomain site are rooted to public.html/
isnt that means my subdomain site is directected to root directory if so then how to access the subdomain files to main directory cause there is no subdirectory for my subdomain site inst that currect?

I am a bit confused

Comment: Define the variable in your wp-config.php file and then you can access it wherever you want. hope it helps!!!

Comment: Sorry I have added another note please check

Answer (score 0):

First, in your wp-config.php file, add this:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder/path/to/new/dir' );
```

And second, also in wp-config.php, add this:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://yoursite.com/folder/path/to/new/dir');
```

You can read more about changing the wp-content dir on the Codex.

Comment: all my subdomain site are rooted to public.html/
isnt that means my subdomain site is directected to root directory if so then how to access the subdomain files to main directory cause there is no subdirectory for my subdomain site inst that currect?
I am a bit confused

Comment: please check subdomain directory. You can use public.html/ directory for subdomain.

Comment: i set all my subdomain directory  public_html/ when i created subdomain to doesnt that mean that my subdomain directory is public_html/ ?